# R how to get a vector of latitudes from a regular tif using brick

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have a tif file that I read in using brick.  I can see the spatial extend of the tif file:

```
b<-brick("t.tif")
b 
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.0001851853, 0.0001851854  (x, y)
extent      : -18.61944, -18.61759, 37.83856, 37.84041  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /scratch/tompkins/water_allafrica/t.tif 
names       :   t 
min values  :   0 
max values  : 255 

extent(SpatialPoints(b))
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -18.61935 
xmax        : -18.61769 
ymin        : 37.83865 
ymax        : 37.84031
```

But I can't work out how to get a vector of latititudes and longitudes easily that I need to define a netcdf file header which I want to write out.  I could do it manually but I am presuming there is a built in function that is easier to use.

Example input file here: http://clima-dods.ictp.it/Users/tompkins/stackoverflow/t.tif

Comment: did you try `sp::coordinates(b)`?

Comment: no I didn't...  thanks - In order to extract the vectors I could use unique e.g. lon=unique(coordinates(b)[,1]),  lat=unique(coordinates(b)[,2]), but is that dangerous due to rounding error do you think?

Comment: it's probably not optimal. What should the vectors represent? The coordinates of the cell centers or the corners?

Comment: sorry I'm probably using the wrong term, when I say "vector", I simply mean a list, e.g. a list of the x and y coordinates that coordinates(b) gives (the grid is regular).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you need:

```
ext <- extent(b)

lat <- seq(ext@ymin,ext@ymax,res(b)[2])
lon <- seq(ext@xmin,ext@xmax,res(b)[1])
```

So basically your're creating a sequence vector from x/y min to max with spacing of the brick's resolution.

The values refer to the corner coordinates of the cell ... you could be also interested in the cell centers.

Just for illustration:

```
# create testraster
x <- raster(resolution=c(40,40))

x[]<- 1:ncell(x)

# plot

plot(x)

# add corner coordinates


plot(SpatialPoints(cbind(rep(extent(x)@xmin,10),seq(extent(x)@ymin,extent(x)@ymax,res(x)[2])),proj4string = crs(x)),
     col='red',pch='*',cex=5,add=T)


# add cell centers

plot(SpatialPoints(xyFromCell(x,cellFromRowCol(x,1:nrow(x),1)),proj4string = crs(x)),
     col='blue',pch='*',cex=5,add=T)
```

[image]

So the method above gives you the latitudes indicated by the red asterisks. If you need the blue ones, you could use `xyFromCell` which returns the coordinates of a raster's cell.